# ABC - the names are tricky to see

Tags: riddle

To get from A to B,
requires steps three.

To get from B to A,
takes four steps they say.

If C is for the rest, 
How call it the best?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not completely sure of the answer but I think this is related to

> Days of the week

Pre-sorting

> First, consider the days of the week sorted *alphabetically* 
>  **A.** Friday 
>  **B.** Monday 
>  **C.** Saturday 
>  **D.** Sunday 
>  **E.** Thursday 
>  **F.** Tuesday 
>  **G.** Wednesday

To get from A to B, requires steps three.

> The number of days between **Friday** and the next **Monday** is three.

To get from B to A, takes four steps they say.

> The number of days between **Monday** and the next **Friday** is four.

If C is for the rest,

> **Saturday** is the first full day of the weekend

How call it the best?

> Saturday is considered by many as the best day of the week for socialising and personal enrichment.

Comment: I'm impressed. It's not **entirely** correct but you've cracked it. There's a single day that is very specially said to be for rest. Saturday is the first free day in many places but in others, they work 6 days week. However, there's one that is claimed to be non-working (depending on your religious view it may vary, though, hehe). If we go by the Bible, the big guy rested then...   :)